# Printing PDF to Dot Matrix Printer Result Font not Clear (PDFsharp)

Tags: pdf, printing, pdfsharp

I have program that create a PDF file (with PDFsharp) then I have to print that PDF to dot matrix printer (Epson LQ-2190)
The problem is the text font that get print is not clear at all. What should I do about this? I can print from notepad with no problem.

Do I have to change the resolution? Can it be done with PDFsharp?

Comment: As @PDFsharp already indicated in his answer, please supply code and sample PDF to allow analysis.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to print the PDF to Dot Matrix with Clear font, But need to change the Printer Device Settings.

Printer Properties -> Preferences -> Paper/Quality -> Advanced -> Graphic, Set the Paper Quality as **240 x 144 dots per inch**  and Under the Document Options Set the **Halftoning as super cell** and also change the paper size as A4 under **Paper/Output.**

it might be required to set **Page Scaling** as **None** or **Custom** and **Reverse** **Pages** check in Main Printer Screen if it's changing the direction while printing.

I hope this information could be help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to print on a DMP: in the best case the application sends the ASCII codes only and the printer prints the text using the built-in fonts.

With other fonts, the text will be converted to bitmaps by the printer driver. Results should still be clear.

In the worst case, you add bitmaps to the PDF file. Results may look poor on the printer.

Normally PDFsharp will create PDF files with vectorized fonts. There is no resolution with vector fonts and if you zoom in with Adobe Reader to 6400% you still see crisp and clear letters.
If you don't see this with your PDF files then you have to change something about the way you create the PDF files.
If you see fonts crisp and clear on the screen, then the problem is with the printer driver.

You don't share a PDF file so we cannot check if there is a problem with the PDF file.

Comment: Hi, I've changing the cpi and the result is better. but still not good. (with courier new).  But now I've use calibri and the result is better.